# Which engine does Stack Overflow use to generate edit history?

Tags: support, stack-exchange, diff, technology

What is the engine that Stack Overflow uses for the comparison of the two question versions? Below is an example from Math Stack Exchange:

[image]

I'd like to use a similar solution for my website, but really can't find anything good for HTML differencing and visualizing.

Comment: Given that everything boils down to markdown, it would be some sort of Markdown Diff visualiser I'd say. Could be self-rolled rather than an off-the-shelf component though.

Comment: @Robotnik self rolled indeed, see the dupe for details.